# Asp.NET Core StaticFiles Cors Errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a project in .NET Core 3.1. While front-end developing in React, I have a little problem with Static files (.doc,.pdf) that are saved in the wwwroot folder. When I call this file from UI then catch Cors Error.
We added Cors Configuration in Startup.cs. Every thing is good but static files not working. Please help to me

Answer (score 3):

Cors won't applied if you are using Static Files feature with the IApplicationBuilder extension method UseStaticFiles().
You have to use the `OnPrepareResponse` to serve CORS headers and inject the `ICorsService` and `ICorsPolicyProvider` into the Statup Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ICorsService corsService, ICorsPolicyProvider corsPolicyProvider)
{

    // ...

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        OnPrepareResponse = (ctx) =>
        {
            var policy = corsPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(ctx.Context, "CorsPolicy")
                .ConfigureAwait(false)
                .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var corsResult = corsService.EvaluatePolicy(ctx.Context, policy);

            corsService.ApplyResult(corsResult, ctx.Context.Response);
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This was the key piece of information we were missing, we were getting CORS errors while generating a PDF from HTML and it turns out that even though the font was on the same domain, fonts still request CORS. Adding this to the static files config fixed the issue. +1